# Looking for a good hdd/external hdd

Tags: hard-disk, data-storage

I'm looking for a way to upgrade my Dell Vostro 470's space for not a lot of money.

Requirements:

- Under $50
- 1TB+ storage
- Have the cable for the motherboard with it (if not then add a link to one with your answer)
- Reliable brand

BONUSES

- Would be great if it were a USB-external drive
- Would be useful if had warranty (can be purchased separately, for $10 or lower)

Options:

----------**OPTION A**----------

I found this HDD for $27

[Link](https://www.google.com/search?biw=320&bih=392&noj=1&tbs=vw:l,mr:1,p_ord:p,cat:380,pdtr0:10%7C1000.0%241000.0,price:1,ppr_max:60&tbm=shop&q=1tb+hard+drive&tbas=0&sa=X&ved=0CDQQvStqFQoTCOGvzIeK_cgCFULmJgodr6UC2A#spd=3682794406269387611&spud=0)

*However when I go on the site (sierracompenents.com or something along those lines) it says minimum amount: $200, but when I go to cart, I says 'Amout: 1' & 'Price: $27' , but is this a glitch? [I'm going to contact them]

1TB (+)
Case (-)
$27 price tag (-)
No Sata cable (-)
New (+)
No warranty details (-)
WD brand (+)
Not external (-)

----------**OPTION B**----------

[Link](https://www.sierracomponent.com/product/components-peripherals/data-storage/internal-hard-drives/hde721010sla330-hitachi-deskstar-e7k1000-32mb-hard-drive-2000019204312-used/)

1TB (+)
Case (+)
$35 price tag (+)
No Sata cable (-)
Used (-)
No warranty details (-)
WD brand (+)
Not external (-)

----------**OPTION C**---------

Must meet the requirements at the top page, Sata cable does not need to be included with hard drive shipment but needs to be with answer.

----------**OPTION D**----------
 [Link](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/wd-elements-1tb-external-usb-3-0-2-0-portable-hard-drive-black/9291106.p?id=1219011381217&skuId=9291106&ref=06&loc=01&ci_src=14110944&ci_sku=9291106&extensionType=pla:g&s_kwcid=PTC!pla!!!58460710247!g!M!87087641359&kpid=9291106&k_clickid=224ab437-b9dc-4847-8f65-510194ae4307&lsft=ref:212,loc:1&ksid=224ab437-b9dc-4847-8f65-510194ae4307&ksprof_id=8&ksaffcode=pg27&ksdevice=m)

1TB (+)
Case (+)
$55 price tag (--)
USB cable (+)
New (+)
3 year warranty (++)
WD brand (+)
external (+)

Bonuses:
From BestBuy (reliable service)
1 day shipping

=============================
Thanks to   [Zizouz212](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/128/zizouz212)  for suggesting the edit.
If you make a post, please make sure that there are many left in stock as I am going to be finalizing my shopping for Christmas.

Answer (score -3):

[Toshiba Canvio Connect II (HDTC810XK3A1)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00R4O9M4A) external 1TB drive is on sale.

- $50
- External 1TB Drive
- Toshiba
- Amazon return policy + manufacturer warranty
- Comes with USB 3.0 standard cable